# Carrierwave store method selection on-the-fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, storage, carrierwave

Is there any existing solution to select store method on the fly in carrierwave?
I wish to select local store or fog (two providers) store on record (user) basis.
Do i have to rewrite my models to inherited models or there is other solution already?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your model from uploader using the `model` method

To specify custom store dir, you can use

```
 storage :fog
```

So, you can write your own macro-class-method which will call storage :for or local based on preference, should be possible but I don't know what you want to archieve exactly. Providing more code (The user code and the conditions on which storage depends) would be helpful.